# table header inside another

Tags: html

i want to span a heading element to include another sub headings  elements like that:

```
<thead>   
<th rowspan="2">main heading1</th>   
<th rowspan="2">main heading2</th>   
<th colspan="3">main heading3
    <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>sub heading1</th>
     <th>sub heading2</th>
     <th>sub heading3</th>
     <tr>
    <thead>   
</th>   
<th rowspan="2">main heading4</th> 
</thead>
```

is that possible ?

Comment: What do you want that to look like?

Comment: Why don't you show us exactly what you want the layout to look like? I'm sure that there is a better way to solve this rather than a table inside another table :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want a table inside a table, you need to use the `<table>` element again. You can't just place another `thead` inside the `thead`. You're also missing `<tr>` tags and if you want a table inside a table using `rowspan` and `colspan` incorrectly.

**Option 1: You could use 2 rows in your `thead`.**

```
<thead>   
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">main heading1</th>   
    <th rowspan="2">main heading2</th>   
    <th colspan="3">main heading3</th>   
    <th rowspan="2">main heading4</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>sub heading1</th>
    <th>sub heading2</th>
    <th>sub heading3</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

**Option 2: A table inside a table.**

```
<thead>   
  <tr>
    <th>main heading1</th>   
    <th>main heading2</th>   
    <th>main heading3
      <table>
        <thead>
         <tr>
           <th>sub heading1</th>
           <th>sub heading2</th>
           <th>sub heading3</th>
         <tr>
        <thead>  
      </table> 
    </th>   
    <th>main heading4</th> 
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: it would be better if you add `tbody` as well for anyone who is looking for the complete solution